# Pandas Assign Dataframe name by value in list

Tags: pandas

I have a list `l=['x','y']`

I want to make 2 blank dataframes called x and y by a loop from the list `l`.

So something like this

```
for v in l:

     v=pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary?

Comment: I not sure how to do that

Comment: So you want to replace initial values 'x' and 'y' with the empty dataframe objects?

Comment: yes so assign a empty dataframe to x. so x=pd.DataFrame()

Comment: and y=pd.DataFrame()

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like,

```
l = []
length = 2
for i in range(length):
    l.append(pd.DataFrame())
```

Or if you really want to modify the initial list with strings,

```
l = ['x', 'y']
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = pd.DataFrame()
```